# How can I sort a 2D List using lambdas/streams per row?

Tags: java, list, sorting, arraylist, 2d

I have a matrix and I am wondering if there is any way to sort this per row, I already tried sorting it manually by traversing the ArrayList and comparing it per element in each row but it seems tedious. Is there any better way for me to sort this. I was thinking of using lambdas/streams

I have following list of list of strings,

```
List<List<String>> matrix = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

Let's say matrix contains the ff:

```
sad,eat,air,vice,ride
cash,grade,save,hide,are
twin,grid,goose,hey,shade
```

The output after sorting would be:

```
air,eat,ride,sad,vice
are,cash,grade,hide,save
goose,grid,hey,shade,twin
```

Solved my problem by using a loop and comparator to sort it the way I wanted. Here's the code:

```
for (List<String> row : matrix) {
                row.sort(Comparator.comparing(r -> r.getString()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
matrix.forEach(row -> Collections.sort(row));
```

Comment: @Roy can you explain why it isn't an answer? Seems to me that it addresses OP's problem perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `forEach()` for the main list and `sort()` for each of the sub-list:

```
matrix.stream().forEach(m -> {
    System.out.print(m.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
    System.out.println();
});
```

Comment: Can anyone explain why above approach is not valid?